# Keynote - View slide as at end of all animations

Tags: macos, keynote, iwork

I am working on my first Keynote presentation, and my first slide has a series of complex animations which results in a slide which is very different from how it started. I wish to maintain the end state of the first slide when I transition into the next slide so that I can keep some continuity in the story.

I was wondering, is there any way of viewing the final state of a slide, after all animations are complete? I can then copy everything into the next slide. I'm not able to find anything that would let me do this. The designer only shows me elements as at the beginning sans any translations/animations.

Answer (score 4):

Yep - can be done - a bit fiddely though. I have this problem all the time. I wish KN would provide an easy solution.

1. Duplicate your slide with all the animations intact.
2. Open your 'Build Order' window.
3. In the Build Order window click on the animation build you want to be static.
4. In your slide you see the object before *and* after it's animation action.
5. Click (twice) on the object in its before animation position.
6. Literally move it until it is on top of the 'end' of its animated path - it should snap into position on top of itself.
7. Release the object when your happy it's exactly on top of itself and delete it's animation build in the Build Order window.
8. Do this for all animations.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use **Magic Move** to achieve the effect you want, but it doesn't work like you are describing. It's a **Transition** (i.e. available when no objects are selected) which ties a slide to the next one. The basic steps:

1. Make a slide
2. Duplicate it
3. Set the Transition of the First slide to "Magic Move"
4. Transform the objects on the second slide.

When you play it, objects will perform their various transformation when you click to go to the new slide.

Note that it seems the magic move effects *stack* with the animations, you may be surprised if you have animations which do similar things to what happens in your Magic Move.

Please refer to the builtin Help for details.

Comment: thank you!!! this just saved me hours.

Comment: This is, hands down, the way to go! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A really quirky workaround would be to export the slides as PDF or images including all the animation phases and then insert the final animation phase into the new slide.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but when copying the final state into the new slide all the sizes and positioning were messed up.

I have decided to try and do a one slide wonder... dissolving through headings as I go rather than switch slides. Only problem is my presenter notes are now monolithic, but I can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

To skip all the animation of a particular slide and go to the final stage, you can go to that slide, then do the following:

- press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>
- and then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>